# Android App switching activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've been working on my first true Android app for a few weeks, and I've been running into a bit of a problem. My app utilizing the Eclipse with the Android ADK can connect to a database that I have on a site, but when it tries to move towards the next activity it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Login.Java snippet:

```
   success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent n = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(n);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
```

ReadComments.class snippet:

```
public class ReadComments extends Activity{

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.read_comments);
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
menu.add("Register")
    .setIntent(new Intent(this,Register.class));
menu.add("New Reservation")
    .setIntent(new Intent(this, NewReservation.class));
menu.add("About Luxury Parking")
.setIntent(new Intent(this, Aboutus.class));
return true;


}

}
```

Comment: Does it crash? If so post your logcat. Also, try calling `startActivity(n);` before `finish()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `finish()` before you call `startActivity(n)`; Calling `finish()` will destroy the activity, hence the other activity not starting. Also don't forget to declare it within your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is manifest xml file changes.

Here is a sample, enter this under **application** tag ;

```
<activity android:name="mete.gcm.info" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
```

**mete.gcm** is my folder name (under src folder) **info** is my activity name.